# Is null check needed before calling instanceof?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

Will `null instanceof SomeClass` return `false` or throw a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: It's also 'important' or at least very useful as a 'best-practise' starting(or very early) line for for any Compare or Equals or similar method that is designed to only succeed on non-null objects of the same type, and guards you against the 'silly cases' in a single line. less code = less bugs.

Comment: To weigh in on the "is this useful?" debate - I've never written my own Java code (so don't easily know where the specs are, and compiling a test would be very non-trivial), but I'm currently manually converting Java to JavaScript.  My code was failing on a null reference, and googling this let me see the accepted answer, which confirmed that it was expected behavior and that I was missing an implicit null check.  Very useful, in my case.

Comment: I have leveraged the fact that `instanceof` checks for `null` to implement a very tight Java `equals()` implementation that reads way cleaner than those I see auto-generated by Eclipse and IntelliJ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75402885/501113

Answer (score 2181, accepted):

No, a null check is not needed before using `instanceof`.

The expression `x instanceof SomeClass` is `false` if `x` is `null`.

The Java 11 Language Specification expresses this concisely in [section 15.20.2, "Type comparison operator instanceof"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2). ([Java 17 expresses this less concisely](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2), after the introduction of `instanceof` pattern matching.)

> "At run time, the result of the
> `instanceof` operator is `true` if the
> value of the *RelationalExpression* **is
> not `null`** and the reference could be
> cast to the *ReferenceType*
> without raising a `ClassCastException`.
> Otherwise the result is `false`."

So if the operand is null, the result is false.

Comment: This answer is more correct than `try it` because **current behavior** is not the same as **guaranteed behavior**.

Comment: This question comes into play during Joshua Bloch's chapter on object equality in `Effective Java` - http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683

Comment: Specifically, in Item 8, he notes that in equals() methods, one instanceof operator serves two purposes - it verifies that the argument is both non-null and of the correct type. "...[S]o you don't need a separate null check."

Comment: I don't see them ever changing this. It can only return true or false so how can can it ever be true for a null reference to be an instanceof anything?

Comment: @BenThurley - Java's `instanceof` operator was part of Java 1.0, released almost 20 years ago. Changing the behavior now in a way that would break existing code is unlikely, absent some benefit that outweighs that huge cost. Twenty years ago, maybe there could have been arguments for returning true iff the argument could be cast, or throwing an exception for a null argument. But those definitions would have required separate null checks.

Comment: Exactly my point. It's true that current behaviour is not the same as guaranteed behaviour but in this case I think it's pretty well guaranteed.

Comment: @BenThurley - The behavior is guaranteed by Java specifications past and present. I think Luke's point addresses the limitations of experimentation in determining the guaranteed behavior of the present.

Comment: Why the compiler let you do this: "null instance of Class" lol. I mean, if it is a hardcoded null, it doesn't make sense to even ask it

Comment: @GabrielBB that’s like writing with a red pen on a red paper. Even if it makes no sense, it’s possible due to the general possibility to combine an arbitrary pen with an arbitrary paper. And implementing a “writing on the same color” check into a pen would complicate the technology for little to no benefit.

Comment: @GabrielBB meanwhile, also a great help in avoiding NPE, for example when you do `if (myObj instance of SomeClass)`

Comment: Interestingly, this is the major way instanceof differs from a typecast. When v is null, `v instanceof C` is false, while `(C)v` throws a `ClassCastException`.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se19/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.checkcast

Answer (score 322):

Using a null reference as the first operand to `instanceof` returns `false`.

Comment: (And now it takes 10 seconds to find this question in Google)

Comment: While using `!null` as the first operand to `instanceof` also returns `false`. Fun!

Comment: @MrYellow that would be a syntax error, need to use parentheses.

Comment: It's valid syntax, just confusing. `!null` is truthy.

Comment: @MrYellow Note that the question was about Java and not JavaScript or other languages with concepts like "truthy"

Answer (score 86):

Very good question indeed. I just tried for myself.

```java
public class IsInstanceOfTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        String s;

        s = "";

        System.out.println((s instanceof String));
        System.out.println(String.class.isInstance(s));

        s = null;

        System.out.println((s instanceof String));
        System.out.println(String.class.isInstance(s));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
true
true
false
false
```

**[JLS / 15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)**

> At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is `true` if the value of the *RelationalExpression* is not `null` and the reference could be cast to the *ReferenceType* without raising a `ClassCastException`. Otherwise the result is `false`.

**[API / Class#isInstance(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-)**

> If this `Class` object represents an interface, this method returns `true` if the class or any superclass of the specified `Object` argument implements this interface; it returns `false` otherwise. If this `Class` object represents a primitive type, this method returns `false`.

Comment: Kind of confusing. s is a String because it says "String s", s is not a String because it is null. So what the hell is s?

Comment: @KaiWang `s` is just an object reference variable. It may refer an actually existing object(`""`) or it may refer a(the) `null` literal reference.

Comment: I'm still confused. s might be null now, but it can only be pointed to a String instance later. It can not be pointed to, like, an Integer. So it is still kind of a String, even it is a null. Just doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @KaiWang You are confusing the variable type with the type of the actual object.  Variables aren't instances; they're effectively just pointers.  `null` isn't string data, no matter what variable is pointing to it.  `s instanceof String` is not the same as `field.getType().equals(String.class)`, for example.

Comment: @KaiWang you have to imagine that in the call `s instanceof String` the `s` gets replaced with the actual value, so that would become `"" instanceof String` and `null instanceof String`. Thinking about it like this may make more sense.

Comment: @KaiWang The `instanceof` operator checks if a value is an instance of a certain type, **not if a value is assignable as (castable to) a certain type**. `null` is not an instance of any type, but it can still be assigned to a variable of any type. This is why `instanceof` always returns `false` for `null`, but any reference variable of an object type can hold a value of `null`.

Comment: @Kröw, "not an *instance of* any type"?  Be careful there with "instance".  `null` "is of the null type" (Java Language Specification for se8, section 3.10.7) AND section 4.1: "There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null (§3.10.7, §15.8.1), which has no name."  You can look further into the SE8 JLS if you like [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.1)

Comment: @KaiWang you're right, it really is confusing. This is why null is often considered to be a hole in the type system. It makes a little more sense if you focus on the "instance" part of instanceof: null is not an instance of anything.

Answer (score 28):

No, it's not. `instanceof` would return `false` if its first operand is `null`.

Answer (score 26):

Just as a **tidbit**:

Even `(`**`((A)null)`**`instanceof A)` will return `false`.

---

(If typecasting `null` seems surprising, sometimes you have to do it, for example in situations like this:

```
public class Test
{
  public static void test(A a)
  {
    System.out.println("a instanceof A: " + (a instanceof A));
  }

  public static void test(B b) {
    // Overloaded version. Would cause reference ambiguity (compile error)
    // if Test.test(null) was called without casting.
    // So you need to call Test.test((A)null) or Test.test((B)null).
  }
}
```

So `Test.test((A)null)` will print `a instanceof A: false`.)

---

P.S.: If you are hiring, please don't use this as a job interview question. :D

Comment: Regarding your PS: If someone is actually supplying gotcha questions in an interview, they are too junior to be interviewing.  The right or wrong answer to any question should never matter in an interview.  It's the **ensuing conversation** around the topic that matters.

Answer (score 6):

No, a `null` check is not needed before calling `instanceof`. It always returns false if its value is `null`.

As per [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) for comparison using `instanceof`.

> At run time, the result of the instanceof operator is true if the
> value of the RelationalExpression is not null and the reference could
> be cast to the ReferenceType without raising a ClassCastException.
> Otherwise the result is false

Hence we can infer that java has something called `null` type also, and this null type is checked in `instanceof` operator which obviously returns false because it is expecting a specific type.

There are two kinds of types in the Java programming language: primitive types and reference types.
As per [Java Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) on types and value

> There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null,
> which has no name. Because the null type has no name, it is impossible
> to declare a variable of the null type or to cast to the null type.
> The null reference is the only possible value of an expression of null
> type. The null reference can always undergo a widening reference
> conversion to any reference type.

From Java 14 onwards and esp. in LTS Java 17 we have an enhanced `instanceof`. We have pattern matching feature which performs casts after type comparisons.

Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object testObject = "I am a string";
    List<Object> testList = null;
    if (testList instanceof List) {
        System.out.println("instance of list");
    } else {
        System.out.println("null type");
    }
    //Enhanced instanceof with type conversion - tested with JDK 17
    if (testObject instanceof String str) {
        System.out.println(str.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Output

```
null type
I AM A STRING
```

Answer (score 3):

- null check is not needed **before instanceof**
- null check is not needed **after instanceof that validates to true**

The following are null-safe:

```java
if(couldbenull instanceof Comparable comp){
   return comp.compareTo(somethingElse);
}
```

```java
//java < 14
if(couldbenull instanceof Comparable){
   return ((Comparable)couldbenull).compareTo(somethingElse);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `instanceof` operator does not need explicit `null` checks, as it does not throw a `NullPointerException` if the operand is `null`.

At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is true if the value of the relational expression is not `null` and the reference could be cast to the reference type without raising a class cast exception.

If the operand is `null`, the `instanceof` operator returns `false` and hence, explicit null checks are not required.

Consider the below example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         if(lista != null && lista instanceof ArrayList) {                     //Violation
                System.out.println("In if block");
         }
         else {
                System.out.println("In else block");
         }
}
```

The correct usage of `instanceof` is as shown below,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      
         if(lista instanceof ArrayList){                     //Correct way
                  System.out.println("In if block");
         }
            else {
                 System.out.println("In else block");
         }  
}
```