# PMD: how to deal with no need to check null before instanceof

Tags: null, instanceof, pmd

Hi i have the following code.

```
if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null
                && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                        .getPrincipal() instanceof User)
```

When I check with pmd it is giving me an warning: No need to check null before instanceof.

Q1.) How do you fix this warning? 
-- if i just do security `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` and getAuthentication is null than I would get NPE (Null pointer exception).

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950319/is-null-check-needed-before-calling-instanceof: if the value is null, `instanceof` returns `false`.

Comment: Tonio, you might want to re-read the question. He can't safely get the value without checking an intermediate result for null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use the fixed version of PMD, add a temporary variable

```
... principal = null;
if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null)
   principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                    .getPrincipal();
if (principal instanceof User) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug in PMD because I face the same problem. Maybe the XPath Expression for this pattern is not clear enough.
But it is already fixed. See
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2317099&group_id=56262&atid=479921