# What's the correct way to override equal method in java?

Tags: java

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Person p) {
        System.out.println("..............");
        return p.name.equals(this.name);
    }
}
```

Hi, I was going through OCJP question and answer and answer to this question was  **The equals method does NOT properly override the Object.equlas method.**

I think it is redundant to override here with name which is String but this answer to this question is also not correct.

Could you please point out what concept i am missing here...

Note: There are no option saying override hasCode and equlas with same parameter to this question...

Comment: first of all, remove the `System.out.println`..

Comment: Why don't you use the IDE to generate one for you?

Comment: Hint: try using `@Override`, and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding the java equals() method quirk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The signature of `equals` should be :

```
public boolean equals(Object p)
```

Your `public boolean equals(Person p)` method doesn't override `Object`'s `equals`. It overloads it.

A possible implementation :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if (!(other instanceof Person))
        return false;
    Person p = (Person) other;
    return p.name.equals(this.name);
}
```

Comment: public boolean equals(Object p){return ((Person)p).name.equals(this.name);} This is the correct signature right?

Comment: @RajeshKumar: [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)

Comment: @RajeshKumar Not quite. Before casing `p` to `Person`, you should validate that it's actually an instanceof Person.

Comment: @LocHa If `name` may be null, you have to test for that scenario and return a proper value, but I'm assuming that a Person without a name is not a possible scenario (the constructor of Person should contain a validation that would prevent that).

Answer (score 7):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object ob) {

    if (!(ob instanceof Person)) {
        return false;
    }

    Person p = (Person)ob;

    return p.name.equals(this.name);
}
```

ClassCastException proof
NullPointerException proof ([Is null check needed before calling instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950319/is-null-check-needed-before-calling-instanceof))

Comment: additional I would add: if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Persona other = (Person) obj;

Comment: passing null can be valid sometimes