# Why or why not use instanceof to check if not null

Tags: java, android

I just wonder if there is a good reason or practice of when to use `!= null` instead of `instanceof` to check if something is null.

Is a bad practice to test if something is null with `instanceof` ?

For example:

```
View view = ((Activity) context).findViewById(viewID);
                                if (view instanceof  View) {
                                    listener.onView(view, viewID);
                                }
```

or

```
View view = ((Activity) context).findViewById(viewID);
                            if (view != null) {
                                listener.onView(view, viewID);
                            }
```

Shouldn't it works just as same?

Comment: If you want to check for nullity, why on earth *would* you use `instanceof`?

Comment: _"Is a bad practice to test if something is null with instanceof"_ **Yes**. It might not even work correctly.

Comment: @JonasCz I don't agree, why the double check is required.

Comment: Perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950319/is-null-check-needed-before-calling-instanceof

Comment: Use `instanceof` if and only if you're checking whether something is an instance of a type. Even though it returns false for null (and theoretically `instanceof Object` equals `!= null`), there's no point to do that and it would even be less readable.

Comment: @JonSkeet I might use 'if (view != null)' or 'if (view instanceof View)'

Comment: @jdv I saw this question before make mine. But I was looking for a explanation of Why do it or why don't.

Comment: Yes, the related question is about why and when, not necessarily how. But the best answer shows that instanceof is a valid way to test for null, and some famous people may advocate it -- see the reference there for examples from Bloch. My advice is that code is read by two compilers: the JDK and the other humans reading your code. I tend to write for the latter over the former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on what you are actually checking

- If you just want to know whether the reference is `null`, use `x == null` and nothing else
- If you want to know whether a particular reference is not `null` and points to an instance of type `Foo` you may use `x instanceof Foo` as it implies being not `null`

  But if the compile-time type of the reference is already `Foo`, you know that the instance is of type `Foo` when it is non-`null`, therefore the first bullet applies in this case; you just want to test for `null`. This is the case in your updated question’s example, the reference already has the compile-time type `View`.
- If you want to know whether a type cast `(Foo)x` will succeed, you may use `x == null || x instanceof Foo` as the type cast will also succeed when `x` is `null` (however, you should think twice whether you really want to accept `null`s, even if the type cast will be successful)

Comment: Really good explanation. What do you think about the example code case ?

Comment: As said, the compile-time type is already `View`, so it should be a plain `null`-test using `… == null` as it’s guaranteed that non-`null` references point to instances of `View`. As a basic rule of thumb, if you don’t need a type cast, you usually don’t need an `instanceof`.

Comment: Do you know if more JVM instructions are executed to a 'instanceof' than '!= null'

PS: I think it does (probably does), just to confirm the thoughts.

Comment: Well, you can encode a `null` test with a single [`ifnull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ifnull) or `ifnonnull` instruction whereas an `instanceof` requires one [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.instanceof) instruction, followed by either [`ifne`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.if_cond) or `ifeq`. But that’s irrelevant, at least in earlier JVMs, dynamic type checking was way more expensive than a simple `null` reference comparison. But it’s not that big anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` instruction is used to check if an object is an instance of a certain class.

So, using it to check null value simply makes no sense...

---

In your code snippets you are checking two different things:

- in the first one you are checking if your object is an instance of `View` class
- in the second one you are checking if the object is initialized

So they are not two ways to do the same thing...

Take a look: [use of "Instance of" in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7526817/1061499)

Comment: I did add a example in the question.
Does it don't make sense.

Comment: but as I was discussing with @jdv , don't instanceof check for 'null' anyways.

Comment: `instanceof` checks for `null` but is not an alternative to `!=null`

Answer (score 0):

Null check is not needed at all to check before `instanceof`.
If it's null then during check of instanceof it will return false.

Is a bad practice to test if something is null with `instanceof` ?

During runtime when you are not sure it can be null or not.just simply use `instanceof` it will return false in case of null object.

Answer (score 0):

> I just wonder if there is a good reason or practice of when to use != null instead of instanceof to check if something is null.

Of course there's a reason, the `!=null` can be applied to all objects in Java, but `instanceof`can't be applied to Primitive types it only checks if a given object is instance of a class, that's why we use `!=null` to check for nullity.

> Is a bad practice to test if something is null with instanceof ?

You can use it, but why whould you use `instanceof` if it may cause problems with primitive types and if `!=null` can be applied to all objects.

**EDIT:**

In your case using `if (view instanceof  View)` is much safer because you are using it to test if it's an instance of `View` and in the same time if it's not `null`.

And as you can see in "[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950319/is-null-check-needed-before-calling-instanceof)" you can see that you can use `instanceof` to check for nullity.

Comment: A primitive like an int is not an object so neither comparing it with null or passing it to instanceof is not valid Java. So, it isn't a particularly good way to compare the use of either...

Comment: To add, `String` is not a primitive type.

Comment: What do you think about the case of the example?

Comment: The variable `view` has the declared compile-time type `View` and therefore can’t have another type. Decent IDEs will even warn you about an obsolete `instanceof` test then.

Comment: @Holger You are right I missed that, I corrected my answer.