# Compiler error instance of final class

Tags: java

The following code compiles fine:

```
interface Flyer{ }
class Bat { }

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Bat b = new Bat();
        if(b instanceof Flyer) System.out.println("b is a Bird");
    }

}
```

If we make the `Bat` class `final`, the code doesn't compile:

```
final class Bat { }
```

If the final class implements `Flyer`, it compiles fine:

```
final class Bat implements Flyer { }
```

Anyone care to explain the logic behind this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you make class `Bat` `final`, you're saying that this class can't be sub-classed. Since `Bat` does not implement the interface `Flyer`, the compiler is able to determine that `b instanceof Flyer` can never be `true` and raises an error.

This is specified in JLS [section 15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> If a cast (§15.16) of the *RelationalExpression* to the *ReferenceType* would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the `instanceof` relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the `instanceof` expression could never be true.

Additionally, from [section 15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16) about cast expressions:

> It is a compile-time error if the compile-time type of the operand may never be cast to the type specified by the cast operator according to the rules of casting conversion (§5.5).

In this case, `Bat` can never be cast to `Flyer`: it doesn't implement it and `final` ensures that there can't be sub-classes that would implement it.

---

As you found out, the fixes are:

- Make `Bat` implement `Flyer`: in this case, the `instanceof` operator would always return `true`.
- Remove the `final` identifier, implying that there could be sub-classes of `Bat` implementing `Flyer`.

Comment: Wouldn't `null instanceof X` return true regardless of the "type" of the null instance ? However I can see that this would be very dodgy to let the compiler accept that

Comment: @Dici Actually, [`null instanceof X` is always `false`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950319/is-null-check-needed-before-calling-instanceof).

Comment: Ups... sorry, you're right, I even use this for writing all my `equals` methods. I need a sleep :D

Answer (score 4):

Well, if `Bat` is a final class and it doesn't implement `Flyer`, it can't have any sub-class that would implement `Flyer` either, so `instanceof` can never return true. In such cases the compiler doesn't allow this expression (i.e. `(x instanceof Y)` is only allowed if there's a chance that `x` would contain a reference to an instance that implements or extends `Y`).

In your second snippet `Bat` already implements `Flyer`, so `b instanceof Flyer` would always return `true`, regardless of whether `Bat` is final or not.

Comment: I find it weird (maybe a bad design) that if it's always `false` a compilation error will happen, but if it's *always* `true`, then it's fine.

Comment: Seems logic now... early checking always a good idea.

Comment: @MarounMaroun There is some inconsistency here, I agree.

Comment: @MarounMaroun there's the same for `if (true)` and `if (false)`. The first compiles fine, the second raises a warning. I think the rational is that dead code is worse than  useless checks. If you write some conditional code which will always be executed, well fine, life is just easier than you thought, but if you write some code that will never be reached, you may make wrong assumptions about the behaviour of your program that could cause harm

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Tunaki's reference from the JLS, this is also explicitly explained in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1, quoting relevant rule:

> **If S is a `final` class (§8.1.1), then S must implement T, or a compile-time error occurs.**

An `instanceof` check follows these rules for reference type casts.