# Overwritten equals() method requires null check? (java)

Tags: java, null, equals

I have written a simple equals() method for a class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
    if(obj instanceof Cl) {
        Cl u = (Cl)obj;
        return u.i == i;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As I know, if I want compare if the class object equals to a null object, this returns false because of the instanceof, but according to my uni teacher this is a bad implementation, as the null check is missing. Can someone confirm for me if my theory is correct or not?

Comment: wont that throw NPE ?

Comment: Your uni teacher is incorrect, `obj instaneof` is a `null` safe test (because `null` is only an instance of the NullType). https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707333/2970947

Comment: `cl` should be `Cl` or even better : a **relevant name**. Please follow Java naming conventions : packages, attributes, variables, parameters, method have to start in **lowerCase**, while class, interface should start in **UpperCase**

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `null instanceof NullType` gives me false ;( No NPE though

Comment: What is the type of `i`? If it's anything else than a primitive type, you might want to use `equals` for that, too. Otherwise this looks fine to me.

Comment: There is no type for which `null instanceof` will be true. Mainly because there is no way to get the NullType (which is not the same as the class you found) because it is deliberately not available for you to get.

Comment: Here, this might clear it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950319/is-null-check-needed-before-calling-instanceof

Comment: It’s a matter of taste. An explicit null check makes it clearer to the reader what happens in the code. I always have to think twice before I know what `null instanceof (SomeClass)` does. I don’t myself have any strong opinion either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, a `null` check is not required and should not be there, because in this case there will not be any compile-time error or any exception if obj is `null`, because of the check `if (obj instaceof C1)`.