# Mockito when not returning the expected object

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to return an expected value from a mocked method.

```
TestClass testClass = TestClass.getInstance();
ClassToMock classToMock = Mockito.mock(ClassToMock.class);
testClass.setClassToMock(classToMock);
ExpectedObject expectedObject = new ExpectedObject("1", "2", "3");
when(classToMock.method(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyBoolean(),
                        ArgumentMatchers.any(A.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(B.class))
                .thenReturn(expectedObject);
testClass.invokeTestMethod();
```

The TestClass and invokeTestMethod are like below:

```
public class TestClass {

  private ClassToMock classToMock;

  public void invokeTestMethod() {
     ExpectedObject expectedObj1 = classToMock.method("A", "B", null, null);
     ::
     ::
     ExpectedObject expectedObj2 = classToMock.method("X", "Y", null, null);
     ::
     ::
     ExpectedObject expectedObj3 = classToMock.method("P", "Q", null, null);
     ::
     ::
  }

  public void setClassToMock(ClassToMock ctm) {
     this.classToMock = ctm;
  }
}
```

I have set the classToMock instance on the TestClass, to make sure that the TestClass works on the mock instance.

To make the issue clearer, the method call is happening on the mocked object (classToMock), but, the expected return value (ExpectedObject) is not coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue here: `null` does not match `any(X.class)`, so mocked value will not be returned

If `null` is passed as argument, then the two last argument matchers in place:

- `ArgumentMatchers.any(A.class)`
- `ArgumentMatchers.any(B.class)`

**will not be matched**.

See documentation of [`any(java.lang.Class)`](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any(java.lang.Class)):

> Matches any object of given type, **excluding nulls**.
>   (marked bold to emphasize)

This is because since *Mockito 2.1.0* internally try to evaluate the type (class) of the argument.
And `null` is an empty reference, not pointing to an instanced object. No reference to an object, no class of that object can be evaluated:

```java
null instanceOf A // will evaluate to `false`
null instanceOf B // will evaluate to `false`
```

See [Is null check needed before calling instanceof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950319/is-null-check-needed-before-calling-instanceof#2950415)

#### Solution: use `any()` or `isNull()` to match `null`

To make the *mocked methods* be called inside, use an argument matcher that will match on `null` values passed.

Answer (score 0):

In the first excerpt when method is called with method signature (String, bool, A, B) as parameter, while in the second excerpt is called method with signature (String, String, Object, Object).
So in the second excerpt classToMock.method("A", "B", null, null) returns null.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had set the ClassToMock instance (didn't show in the code, but, had mentioned it in the last line of the first post).

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass `ClassToMock` ro the `TestClass` for example in the constructor on in a set method. This way in the test you can pass your mock to test class and in the method `invokeTestMethod` the mock will be used. At the moment your not doing this, so `method` is called on the real object

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had set the ClassToMock instance (didn't show in the code, but, had mentioned it in the last line of the first post).

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to all who chose to help. I found the fix. In the TestClass, there was a call like this:
`ExpectedObject expectedObj1 = classToMock.method("A", "B", null, null);`
The two null parameters caused the issue. So, I overloaded the `method` inside the `ClassToMock` with the NON NULL parameters. After this change, the mock is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Great you solved and posted a self-answer   Can you explain what you changed exactly, __adding the source__? So anyone having the same issue, can learn from you.

Comment: classToMock method had 4 parameters, out of which two were null in this case. So, I wrote a method in the ClassToMock ```method(param1, param2)``` and passed null for the 3rd and 4th parameter. This way I just avoided passing null from the TestClass method. You helped me passing isNull without overloading the method. Thanks.