# how to determine the Class inside a Collection in Java?

Tags: java

How can I tell what type of class is inside a Collection? I need to handle simple data types differently than complex types and therefore I must know the contained class. At the moment, I have to iterate through the collection to find out the class which doesn't sound right. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651632/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-collection-type-in-java/2651654#2651654) was quite helpful but didn't fully address my issue. Basically, here are the questions:
1. How to determine the class inside the collection?
2. how can I tell if the object is a java wrapper class (Integer, String, Date, etc..) or a proprietary class (Student, Vehicle, etc...).

Thank you
Jabawaba

```
entity = new SomeObject();
Class entityClass = entity.getClass();
for (Method method : entityClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
  Class<?> returnType = method.getReturnType();
  if (returnType != null) {
    if (returnType.isPrimitive() || (returnType.getName().startsWith("java.lang.")) || (returnType == java.util.Date.class)) {
      // handling primitive and wrapper classes
      handleScalar(method);
    } else if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType)) {
      Collection collection = (Collection) method.invoke(entity);
      if (collection == null || collection.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
      }
      for (Object value : collection) {
        if (value.getClass().getName().startsWith("java.lang.") || (value.getClass() == java.util.Date.class)) {
          handleSimpleVector(method);
          // no need to go through all the simple values
          continue;
        } else {
          // Each 'value' is itself a complex object.
          handleComplexObject(method);
        }
      }
    } else if (<return-type-is-an-Array>){
      // do something similar as the above.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've come along way according to the code you posted. So what do you try to accomplish and at what point are you stuck?

Comment: @Platvoet. I'm trying to differentiate the *return* types between: (a) public long getDistance(); (b) public List<Long> getCounts(); (c) public List<Vehicle> getCars(); (d) public Long[] getSizes(); Because I am writing a wrapper for Lucene/Solr and I need to know the accessor's return type to decide what kind of Solr Field I should use.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I feel there is a better way and you're just using the wrong tools.

Comment: Let me rephrase that, just like Amir I'm wondering what the purpose of this piece of code is. Why do you need to differentiate between these methods? There might be a different approach which better suits your needs.

Comment: So you basically want to store just any class in Lucene? In that case you might consider using java's serializable system. Provide your own ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You simply can't if it's not a generically typed Collection. Non-typed Collections can contain any mixture of object types.

If you're dealing with a (non-empty) typed Collection, then you could determine the class of its contents at runtime e.g. by

```
Collection<?> coll = ...
if (coll.isEmpty())
    throw new BadLuckException();
Object representative = coll.iterator().next();
Class<?> typeOfContent = representative.getClass();
//apply your cases on this Class object
```

There's no other way to determine the generic type information at runtime since the generic type is purely compile-time information.

2) Date is not a wrapper class - the primitive classes and their wrappers are:

- short / Short
- int / Integer
- long / Long
- byte / Byte
- char / Char
- double / Double
- float / Float
- boolean / Boolean

You can determine whether your class is a primitive one using [Class#isPrimitive](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive%28%29). Note, however, that this will only determine whether an object is really primitive, it will not determine whether you are dealing with an autoboxed value:

```
System.out.println(Integer.class.isPrimitive()); // -> false
```

But, every wrapper class declares a field named "TYPE" that represents the primitive class it is wrapping. So you can check whether a class is a wrapper class like this:

```
public static boolean isWrapperClass(Class<?> clazz) {
    try {
        clazz.getDeclaredField("TYPE");
        return true;
    catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion. How about a more elegant way than shown above for determining wrapper/primitive vs non-standard class?

Comment: See my edit - I'm afraid there's no other way than the ugly one of comparing the classes explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do?

```
Collection c = new ArrayList();
c.add("Hi");
Iterator i = c.iterator();
Object v = i.hasNext()? i.next() : null;
if(v != null) {
    System.out.println(v.getClass().getName());
}
```

**Update:**

Assuming it is a homogeneous collection. Hopefully I correctly understood your problem.

Comment: I am already doing that in the sample code. I do *not* want to iterate thru the generic collection to figure out the contained class type.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example (Integer, String, Date, etc..), I'd simply create a Set containing all the types you want to handle differently and then just check if value type is in this set. You still have to iterate trough collection elements or assume that all elements of collection are of the same type.

Answer (score -1):

You *can't* determine the type arguments for an unknown collection at run time. That information simply is not kept by the JVM at run time.

Comment: Of course you can. You can do getClass on any object. I think what you mean is the generic type. Which is partially true.

Comment: You can detect the _erased_ type of the collection itself, but there is no way to get at its generic type **arguments** (notice that word in the answer?). You can try to look at the elements themselves, but if there are none or they are all nulls, that will leave you none the wiser.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the **instanceof** keyword like this:

```
if(s instanceof java.lang.String)
{

}
```

[Link to examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm)

Comment: This requires checking each case you are looking for though so it may not be practical

Comment: but then I have to iterate thru the collection items which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Or it may be exactly what you are trying to avoid...my bad!