# cast of object into original type

Tags: java, casting

I'm trying to send a `Collection<myClass>` across a network. I cast it as an Object, and I sent it this way.

I think the best way to modelize the item being passed in the network is through an Object, since I don't know in advance what it might be (in this example, it's a Collection, but some other times it's a Map or any other thing you can think of). This would be somehow like the way sockets work in C, where only the receiver and sender know what they're sending/receiving, and cast the objects appropriately, whereas the connection only cares about bytes and transmitting them properly.

However, when receiving the Object, if I try to cast it back to `collection<myObject>`, a warning mentions unsafe type casting. I could add @suppressWarnings, but what would be the best way to do this cast so as to avoid this warning ?

Thanks

Comment: The proper solution is indeed `@SuppressWarnings`, if you're certain the cast is actually safe.  Any other solution will just suppress the warning somewhere else.

Comment: I don't like to be bound by tools that are supposed to help me, but the fact is that I use 'sonar', and even though I add @SuppressWarnings, I still get an error in sonar. Is there a way to disable the sonar warning too ?

Comment: Are you sure the SONAR warning is for the same reason? What does the warning say?

Comment: Yeah you're right sorry this is another warning. I'm marking this as my answer then... if you would just create an answer out of it.

Answer (score 3):

As you (although, mostly Java) do not know the type of the object that you receive, it is impossible to safely cast it.

Thing you can do:

- You need to be really sure it is the object you think it is
- Maybe add a `try-catch` block to catch `ClassCastException` (to be extra sure)
- And finally add the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation, as you want to override the safety checks of Java (because you think to know better)

Comment: @sdasdadas that won't work I suppose, as you can only create an `Object` instance when receiving the data. If you think you know what you get you can create an object of another type, but then you do not need `instanceof` anymore.

Comment: I was under the impression he was looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651632/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-collection-type-in-java  but perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Comment: That won't help checking that the collection is a Collection<MyObject>.

Comment: @JBNizet But he stated, "in this example, it's a Collection, but some other times it's a Map or any other thing you can think of".

Comment: He asked *what would be the best way to do this cast so as to avoid this warning ?*, and there's simply no way. You can check that it's an instance of Collection, but you can't check that it's an instance of Collection<MyObject>.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using some intermediate format for serialization, like JSON or XML. There are plenty of libraries out there for marshalling and unmarshallling objects into/from JSON. For instance [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). What you get for free is the language interoperability, because on the other hand of the wire there could be a program in any language.

Comment: I'm not against using json or xml (in fact I already have done so in another part of my project), but how does that change the fact that, as the programmer coding the network part, I don't know the type of the object being passed on (only known from sender/receiver) ? What class am I to use, if not Object ?

Comment: -1 doesn't address the OP's concern, and the only effect would be to move the unsafe cast elsewhere

Comment: This is not true, you don't have to cast anything. Look at https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide (Deserialization). In fact using `@SuppressWarnings` is pretty bad programming practice. And most of the time it can be avoided.